# React componentDidUpdate infinite loop even if the state matches

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to update state whenever the component gets updated. I do so because I reuse the component to show different data from the API. But there is a problem - componentDidUpdate creates an infinite loop even though I check if the state is different from the response data.

I will add some code.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=${this.props.match.params.id}`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data !== products) {
          this.setState({ products: res.data, loading: false });
        } else {
          console.log('matches');
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Is there any work-around to avoid making an API request every time the component gets updated? I have an API request in my componentDidMount function, but it works only for the initial render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.data !== products` is performing a reference check, which means it will always return true since `res.data` and `products` point to different objects in memory (unless axios keeps a cache of response objects, which I don't think it does).

One way to accomplish what you want would be to use the `prevProps` argument to [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in order to determine if `props.match.params.id` has changed:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.id === this.props.match.params.id) {
        // no need to do anything since we're still on the same ID
        return;
    }

    // perform the rest of your fetching logic
}
```

Another option would be to perform a deep equality check using something like [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual).

Comment: I believe it should be ```prevProps.match.params.id === this.props.match.params.id```?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, comparing Objects in javascript is a little bit more complicated than comparing strings or numbers.
In your example, you‘re not actually comparing if the objects are equal, but if the *reference* is equal, which is not the case.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) is an example of comparing objects, that might work for you. But I would recommend, depending on how your `res.data` looks like, that you try to compare only some metrics instead of the whole objects, depending on which properties actually change.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ComponentDidMount. In fact, you need to fetch the products list (a priori) only once.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing the entire object/array which will always a different reference,
compare some primitive data.

Something like an id should work fine or the length of array in a case where products are added or removed from the array.